# Internal Server Error after administrator password change... (Mac OSX & PHP)

Tags: php, macos, administrator, internal-server-error

Here at work I recently adopted a rather undocumented Mac OSX/PHP web server. The "administrator" account password was unknown, and another technician reset it before handing the server over to me. The website hosted on the server is running fine, all except one subfolder which generates an "Internal Server Error" when you try to access anything within the subfolder. The file can be a PHP file, HTML file, even one I created (that works just fine when you throw it in the root or any other subfolder that's there.

Trying to access anything in the subfolder does present you with a username/password prompt, but I'm not seeing an .htaccess file in that subfolder. When I successfully log in using the "administrator" account username/password is when the "Internal Server Error" presents itself. I'm not seeing anything in the PHP error logs, making me think it's not getting that far - and I'm also not seeing anything in the server logs.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the right log files?  A 500 internal server error should at least be logged to the Apache error log file as long as it wasn't a 500 error sent by PHP.  Check httpd.conf or the vhosts file for locations of the error logs and also any other configuration that may be prompting for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

By my experience, it sounds like the subfolder does not contain a index-file and the directory listing may be disabled thus causing you to see the "Internal Server Error" as a last resort by the httpd server.
Create a file in the subfolder:

```
touch index.html
```

Password protecting a domain/folder does not require the .htaccess/.htpasswd (or other named file by choice) to exist in the same folder. It can be placed anywhere else the httpd can read it from. I suggest you read through the configuration file for your httpd and also check the php-error log, but in this case I would look in the httpd-error log first.

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out there was an .htaccess in that folder (I guess the Mac OS just hides those), and the .htpasswd file it was referencing (which didn't use the ".htpasswd" naming convention at all) was missing altogether. Not sure what caused that to happen... but everything is working once again.